# Restringir Visualización de Filas por Usuario

Tags: sql, visual-studio

Mi tabla principal

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Registro](
    [IDRegistro] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Fecha Ingreso] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Número] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Fecha Documento] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Firmado Por] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Dirigido a] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Ccp] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Estado] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Procedencia] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Tipo Documento] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Asunto] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [TurnadoA] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Fecha turno] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Estatus] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Seguimiento] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Conclusión] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Archivado en] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Registro] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Donde la columna **TurnadoA** es el nombre del Usuario: Dirección, Vinculación, Programación, Implementación, Trámites. El Usuario Dirección es el Administrador.

A continuación, el código del Login en Visual Studio

```
public class DLogin
{
    private Conexion connection = new Conexion();
    private SqlDataReader leer;

    public SqlDataReader iniciarsesion(string user, string pass)
    { 
     SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SpLogin2", connection.AbriConexion());
     comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TurnadoA", user);
     comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass);

        leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
        return leer;

private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CNLOGIN objEmpleado = new CNLOGIN();
        SqlDataReader Loguear;
        objEmpleado.Usuario = txtuser.Text;
        objEmpleado.Contraseña = txtpass.Text;

        //if (objEmpleado.Usuario == txtuser.Text)
        {
            //  lblErrorUsuario.Visible = false;

            //  if (objEmpleado.Contraseña == txtpass.Text)
            {
                //  lblErrorPass.Visible = false;
                Loguear = objEmpleado.IniciarSesion();

                if (Loguear.Read() == true)
                {

                    {
                        {
                            this.Hide();
                            PanelPrincipal ObjFP = new PanelPrincipal();
                            Program.TurnadoA = Loguear["TurnadoA"].ToString();
                            ObjFP.Show();

                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lblErrorLogin.Text = "Usuario o contraseña invalidas, intente de nuevo";
                    lblErrorLogin.Visible = true;
                    txtpass.Text = "";
                    txtpass_Leave(null, e);
                    txtuser.Focus();
                }
            }
```

Mis Tabla esta contenida en una DataGridView en Visual Studio. Lo que quiero lograr es que el usuario Vinculación sólo pueda ver las filas donde diga Vinculación, el usuario Programación sólo pueda ver las filas donde diga programación y así sucesivamente. El usuario Dirección como Administrador verá todo.

Tengo en mente el código SELECT del WHERE sin embargo no se donde colocarlo exactamente para cumplir con la restricción a nivel de fila.

Answer (score 0):

coloco respuesta ya que no puedo comentar.

Primero que nada esta super confusa tu pregunta, no se entiende nada de los enunciados ni la relación que existe con sabe que miles de opciones de usuarios. Trata de dar mas informació o ser mas clara al explicar.

A lo poco que logro entender quieres mostrar informacion diferente dependiendo el usuario, asi en terminos generales te puedo dar tres posibles opciones:

- Identificar en el aplicativo (codigo) el tipo de usuario y mandar a llamar a diferentes SP dependiendo el usuario
- Utilizar un solo SP mandando como parametro el tipo de usuario utilizando [IF EN SQL SERVER](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- Utilizar un solo SP mandando como parametro el tipo de usuario utilizando "WHERE" bien seccionado (usa y ten mucho cuidado con los parentesis)

Ejemplo de la tercera opción y en mi parecer la mas viable

```
WHERE (@parametroTipoUsuario = 'tipo1' AND tabla.campo = 'vinculacion')
    OR (@parametroTipoUsuario = 'tipo2' AND tabla.campo = 'programacion')
    OR (@parametroTipoUsuario = 'tipo3' AND tabla.campo = 'restrinccionX')
    OR @parametroTipoUsuario = 'admin' -- REPITO JUEGA BIEN CON LOS PARENTESIS
```

No creo haber dado respuesta tal cual a tu pregunta por no entender del todo, pero si siento haberte dado una idea.

Espero te sirva. Saludos